# How to call a function which is inside other function

Tags: r, function

I'm trying to equalize the acceleration from a speed vector drawn from the previously reckon of position. The issue is that I don't know if it works with a function inside another function as the following form:

```
SpeedReckon <- function(trip)
{
  speed=3.6*sqrt(diff(trip$x,1,1)^2+diff(trip$y,1,1)^2) 
  return(speed)
}

Acceleration <- function(speed){
  acceleration = cbind(positive,negative) #separation between positive          acceleration and negative  I want to create a variable with two features (positive and negative -> like a list 
  acc = diff(speed) # vector with accelerations
  i=1
  while (i<=length(acc)) #classify positive and negative
  {
    j=1
    if(acc[i]<0)
    {

      while(positive[j]!=NULL){ # I do this in order to add the values in the last space, I don't know if it is necessary
        j=j+1
      }
      positive[j] <- acc[i]
    }
    else{

      while(negative[j]!=NULL){
        j=j+1
      }
      negative[j] <- acc[i]
    }
    i=i+1
  }
  return (acceleration)
}
```

The code from above do not find `acceleration` function, so I guess I'm not calling the `function` properly. Here is the `function` call:

```
trip = read.csv(paste0(dirPath,i,".csv"))
speed = c(SpeedReckon(trip))

feature2 = c(driver,i, Acceleration(speed))
acceleration = rbind(acceleration, feature2)
```

Comment: According to the code you’ve posted, `Acceleration` is *not* inside another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you think `Acceleration` is inside another function, it's not.

Running your code produces the following error:

```
Acceleration(2)
Error in cbind(positive, negative) : object 'positive' not found
```

which is true, you haven't defined `positive` or `negative` anywhere, unless they're defined somewhere else in your code and the scoping rules applied succeed to produce an outcome.

Please, either change the argument list of this function to include `positive` and `negative` or please comment on your question if you are providing the values outside the function as `global variables`